# Separate list of strings into a new list depending on its first letter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of country names

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Bahamas, The
Bahrain
Cambodia
Cameroon
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is separate this list into other lists depending on the first letter.

So basically I want to have a list of countries that begin with a, b, c, ......

Comment: great? what have you tried? hint `.GroupBy(s[0])` (intentionally incorrect syntax)

Answer (score 6):

So, you have a collection of strings. You can use LINQ to group them and convert them to a Dictionary.

First, you'll need to group them based on the first letter (in this situation, case matters so `a` and `A` will be treated differently) using `GroupBy(n => n[0])` where `n[0]` gets the first character in the string.

Second, you'll want to convert the grouping to something that you can use an indexer with. A Dictionary would be perfect. Use `ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g)`.

When you string it together, it'll look like:

```
var dict = names.GroupBy(n => n[0]).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g);
```

And allow you to get the grouped names using:

```
foreach(var n in dict['A'])
{
    // Print out each country starting with 'A'
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: kindly please add seom explanation to make it understandable

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - that is very understandable, if it isn't a little bit of research effort will go a long way

Comment: ``n[0]`` will pick up first index of string. am i right??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - Edited. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var countriesWithStartingLetterA = countries.Where(x => x.StartsWith("A")).ToList();
```

Comment: Wesley Skeen, all you have to do is repeating this code 26 times :)

Comment: ^true, its just for one list with a given letter (seems like i misunderstood the question)